# How to update a specific Recyclerview Row using live data without refreshing entire list

Tags: android, android-livedata

I am learning android and probably this question might have an answer but cant find a way to solve my problem. Ok I am creating a chat application using websocket and works fine but there is a scenario I need to solve that is when a user is chatting on a selected user I need app to have capability to receive text messages from other friends so as to mark as unread and show last received message(just like telegram and whatsapp does) so far on that I have implemented LiveData to do that which work fine as am able to see logs in my console. My issue is on Observe method how do I update a specific item on my list of users to create a notification tally of new messages. Here is my code for live data. The the other issue am stuck with is how to store large text on room database. Am wondering if there is a specific annotation to specify column size.

```
 public class ChatFragment extends Fragment
 
 {
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ChatAdapter adapter;
    private NotificationRepository notificationRepository;
    private NotificationListModel notificationListModel;

 
 public ChatFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    Map<Long,MyFriendsModel> tutor_map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler);


        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        adapter=new ChatAdapter(getActivity(),getUsers());
        adapter.setTutorOnclickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        set_up_live_data();


        return view;
    }
 }
 
 private void set_up_live_data()
 
 {
 
 /***
 I do not know how to update my list of users to create total tallies of unread message and last message on new data from observer
 */
  notificationRepository=new NotificationRepository(mActivity);
        notificationListModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationListModel.class);
        notificationListModel.getLiveNotification().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<NotificationEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<NotificationEntity> itemModels) {//this one is invoked from Websocket onMessageMethod and store them in sqlite

                 Log.e(TAG, "onChanged: ");// am able to see this on the console
                List<MyFriendsModel> msg=new ArrayList<>();
     
                for(NotificationEntity m:itemModels)
                {
                  
                        MyFriendsModel ms=new MyFriendsModel();
                        ms.setLast_message(m.getLast_message());//need to update particular row with this and
                       
                        ms.setTotal_unread(m.getTotal_unread());//need to update particular row with this
                        msg.add(ms);
                
                    
                }
    }
        });
 
 }
 
 private List<MyFriendsModel> getUsers() {
     
        List<MyFriendsModel> messages;//retrofit calls to fetch list of users
       
       
        return messages;
    }
    
    
    public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
      private Context mContext;
     private List<MyFriendsModel> mMessageList;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<MyFriendsModel> messageList) {
        mContext = context;
        mMessageList = messageList;
    }
  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View  view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.chat_item_layout, parent, false);;



        return new MyHodlerHolder(view);
    }

   
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyFriendsModel message = mMessageList.get(position);
        ((MyHodlerHolder) holder).bind(message);

    }
    private class MyHodlerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tutorName,txt_unread_chats,txt_last_sent_message;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        MyHodlerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tutorName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_tutor_name);
            txt_unread_chats=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_unread_chats);
            relativeLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
            txt_last_sent_message=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_last_sent_message);

        }


        public void bind(final MyFriendsModel message)
        {
            tutorName.setText(message.getUser_name());
            txt_unread_chats.setText();//to be updated on by live data. this is where I am stuck.
            //I need to update a specific Item not refreshing the entire list
            
           
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my entity that I need to store large text

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_chats")
public class ChatsEntity
{

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    long id;
    private String message;//need to make this column to store large text
    private String chat_date;
}
```

Comment: I recommend DiffUtil.

Comment: @Eyosiyas kindly share diff util code about it

Comment: @Eyosiyas have not worked with DiffUtill any example to do that

Comment: @Adnanhaider I have not worked with DiffUtill and have not added it anywhere

Comment: @Eyosiyas what about the last part on size of room database column to store large text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend DiffUtil for this situation.

Create a class named **MyDiffUtil**.

```
public class MyDiffUtil extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private List<MyFriendsModel> newList;
    private List<MyFriendsModel> oldList;

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return newList.get(newItemPosition).id == oldList.get(oldItemPosition).id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        if (!oldList.get(oldItemPosition).message().equals(newList.get(newItemPosition).message()))
            return false;
        else if (!oldList.get(oldItemPosition).getUser_name().equals(newList.get(newItemPosition).getUser_name()))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Update your adapter class with.

```
public void populate (List<MyFriendsModel> newMessages) {
    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new MyDiffUtil (mMessageList, newMessages));
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

Instead of adapter=new ChatAdapter(getActivity(),getUsers());
make the necessary changes and call

```
adapter.populate(getUsers());
```

To learn more check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil).

Comment: what about the last part on size of room database column

Comment: using the sample code provide make your change in areContentsTheSame function.

Comment: am ok with the DiffUtil but am asking about the second question on how to specify column length of room database

Comment: @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM table_name") in your DAO and create a method for it.

Comment: am asking suppose i have column message. how do I specify length of the message column let say 1000 chars in my Entity Class

Comment: Use an array of characters with the required size in your POJO class.

Comment: @Eyosisas I dont understand by using array of characters because u see like the way hibernate specify column length i needed that

Comment: The maximum character a String can store in Java is 2,147,483,647( two billion, one hundred forty-seven million, four hundred eighty-three thousand, six hundred forty-seven), so you are fine.

Comment: but when I check on the table created the column size is 255 chars but the message could be longer than this

Comment: your solution on DiffUtil does not work. It does not update the reccycler view!!

Comment: Did you used adapter.populate(getUsers())?

Comment: Yes I did it refresh the list and no change on the specific row that was changed

Comment: Check this adapter.updateRecycler(1,ms) and DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new ChatDiffUtil(mMessageList, newMessages),true);

Comment: Ignore this code adapter.updateRecycler(1,ms);. I was trying that but never worked also after your solution never worked at all

Comment: I found a work around without using diff util